# Change values in an array

Tags: php

I have a field in our CRM system with order numbers: 544,543,53. 
This is an example, the amount and size of these numbers can vary.

**How do I change these numbers to:**

```
HPO0000000544
HPO0000000543
HPO0000000044
```

Please note that the amount of 0s in the HPO codes depends on the size of the order number. HPO should always be followed by 10 numbers (0s + the order number).

Comment: Have you attempted any coding to achieve this specification? If so please show it to us

Comment: To ask On Topic question, please read [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `$number=544;`
`$result = 'HPO'.str_pad($number, 10, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);`

Comment: @RiggsFolly unfortunately I don't know enough about php to code this from scratch, as I haven't been able to find a solution elsewhere. I've asked it here because I know there must be someone who can help me. However, due to the down votes I've now been banned from asking questions for two days...

Comment: @jagad89 I'm working in a workflow automation tool called Globiflow (linked to CRM system Podio). They only allow a limited form of php, and they don't recognise STR_PAD_LEFT or str_pad. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do the following:

```
$prefix = 'HPO';
foreach ($values as $value){
    //loop trhough the values
    $string ='';
    $string = sprintf("%'.010d\n", $value);
    $string = $prefix.$string;
    echo $string;
}
```

sprintf will help you to build complex strings with length control and many more features. See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) for more informations.